# Doxygen: trouble with column width of parameter tables

Tags: latex, doxygen

In the pdf output of Doxygen documentation, the tables of the function parameters have incorrect width. Does anybody have a solution to fix this issue?

[image: see the image below]

Here is the Doxyfile I am using:

```
PROJECT_NAME           = my project name
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 1.0.0
PROJECT_BRIEF          = my project synapsis
PROJECT_LOGO           = logo.png
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ./
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = YES
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = NO
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = NO
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = NO
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= NO
SHOW_USED_FILES        = NO
LAYOUT_FILE            = DoxygenLayout.xml
INPUT                  = ../Source \
                         ./README.md \
                         ../Include/header.h \
                         ../Include/Global_Structs.h
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = ../Source/clencurt_gen.c \
                         ../Source/cubature.c \
                         ../Source/hcubature.c \
                         ../Source/pcubature.c
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = README.md
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = NO
#AM: I modified the header.html file to remove the Project_Name from the #header of the doxygen page. In order to save a header file, first I ran 
#doxygen -w html header.html footer.html customdoxygen.css 
#which creats the three files that doxygen uses to start the html page, and #then costumized the header file.
HTML_HEADER            = ./header.html
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
COMPACT_LATEX          = YES
LATEX_HEADER           = header.tex
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = 
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      = transparent.png
GENERATE_RTF           = YES
GENERATE_MAN           = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = ../Include
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = *.h
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = NO
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = NO
HAVE_DOT               = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
```

And here are the modifications I made to the header.tex file, basically I only changed the titlepage of the latex output.

```
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{center}%
\includegraphics[width=0.7 \textwidth]{../transparent.png}\\
\vspace*{2cm}
{\Large Version 1.0.0}\\
\vspace*{.6cm}
{\Large Developer: name}\\
\vspace*{2.5cm}
{\large $generatedby Doxygen $doxygenversion}\\
%%BEGIN LATEX_TIMESTAMP
\vspace*{0.5cm}
{\small $datetime}
%%END LATEX_TIMESTAMP
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
```

The snippet of the function definition and comments in the C code:

```
/** 
 * Compute the cold dark matter concentration-mass relation
 *   
 * @param M      Input: halo mass in the unit of solar mass
 * @param z      Input: redshift of interest
 * @return the cdm concentration
 */

double concentration_cdm(double M, double z)
{
 
  double result = 0.;

  *
  Do some calculations to compute result 
  *

  return result;
}
```

Comment: From your previous question I gather you are using doxygen version 1.9.2. To be able to say something sensible about the current problem: what are you settings different from the defaults doxygen settings (i.e. the output of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`), show the, minimal, code that causes the the problem (please edit the required information int the question).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added the list of modifications I have made to the Doxyfile.

Comment: To be able to reproduce the problem quite a bit of information is missing, as this is currently just about the LaTeX part the `header.html` is not relevant, but the `header.tex` is so what are the differences here compared to the default `header.tex`? Also the input file in which the parameters are documented is missing. Of interest is also the LaTeX version you are using.

Comment: I added the modification I made to header.tex in the original post above. Basically, all I have changed was the title page setting of the latex output.

Comment: The input files in which the parameters are documented is a rather long C package. As an example here is a function definition comments corresponding to the table above. I posted the snippet of the code in the original question above.

Comment: Searching for similar questions posed on stackhoverflow before, I came across https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6769, and I noticed the response of "simevo" which shows the problem I am having with the table. Though, I didnt manage to find the fix.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but failed i.e. my output looks OK. The mentioned issue is resolved in 1.9.2 so you should not have any problems here (doxygen delivers some compatibility code so we still can use the tabu package). The only things I can think of are - the LaTeX version you use is to old, which version are you using? - did you run the make command on the latex directory?

Comment: Thank you very much for checking. I am using pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018), and yes, I ran make on the latex directory.

Comment: TeX Live 2018 is a few years old but I cannot remember that I had problems with it. I'm running out of ideas. The strange thing for me is the small column. Did you also try it on another computer, maybe it is something local?